# htaccess to capture everything including slash

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a url in form

```
example.com/?title=foo/bar
```

to

```
example.com/foo/bar
```

Placeholder foo and bar
can be a string any character including  ampersand, dots, forward slashes underscore and dashes. Using:
    `RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z/0-9+-]+)$ /?title=$1 [L,NC]`

works for  **alphanumerics + , - /**
Addding `\.`  or `&` the regex gives a

> 500 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your title argument is handled by index.php use below rule,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: could be example.com/foo/bar/baz/qux. I want all captured